# objectivization vs objectification

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm in a bit of a trouble over the words

> **objectivization**
>
> **objectification**

Which of the above would be correct in the context of *making something objective (impersonal, unbiased)*.

I suppose the same issue would be with *subjectification* and *subjectivization*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the one with **objectiv-** in it would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I perceive it this way:

```
objectivization = making something objective
objectification = making something an object
```

Answer (score 0):

*Objectivization* is the act or process of objectifying something.

*Objectification* is the end result of that act.

Answer (score 0):

This question has bothered me too for years, as in dictionaries or online definitions, objectivation/objectification sometimes appear to be synonyms, or at least related words. In searching for an answer, I found a very helpful differentiation between the terms in [Status and Sacredness](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EdqMMcYQ7r8C&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=difference%20between%20objectivation%20and%20objectification&source=bl&ots=lNTs-rg_BA&sig=uVdeqcAJSDOuY8x5Lh7dHgN0IpU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixyorB0onZAhXsCcAKHRjIDBcQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=difference%20between%20objectivation%20and%20objectification&f=false) by Murray Milner Jr., on pp. 99-100.

Milner deliberately treats objectification as a "subtype" of objectivation, in order to explain his own arguments about status symbols, but the explanation seems to me to work well when translated into the other contexts where I have read *objectivation* rather than *objectification* (in the works of sociologists Pierre Bourdieu, and Sylvia Faure).

He illustrates the difference with the example of a "best book of the year award." Such an award is the *objectivation* of the concept of the "best book of the year," as are other physical representations of status such as medals and trophies. By contrast, *objectification* for Milner is "a special subtype of objectivation that involves reification of social processes into near physical or mechanical processes." Returning to the example of the "best book of the year award," *objectification* would be when someone thought that merely owning the prize would give you the status implied by it.

Maybe another example would be a crown: it objectivates the notion of monarchy; but if you believed that stealing and wearing the crown made you the current monarch, then that would be an objectification of monarchy—a belief that monarchy rested in the crown itself as an object, rather than the social processes that enable a monarch to rule.

It's all further complicated by the fact that one or the other of these terms are translations of the German words Verdinglichung, Versachlichung, or Vergegenständlichung (or even Entfremdung/Alienation) (see [Objekt-Subjekt](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4XmiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=Vergegenst%C3%A4ndlichung%20vs.%20versachlichung&source=bl&ots=8FQZv_IaRq&sig=j5cOShFaCLCD1x8-UL9mbjbl2wg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF_YWL24nZAhUEWsAKHddnA5QQ6AEIRjAE#v=onepage&q=Vergegenst%C3%A4ndlichung%20vs.%20versachlichung&f=false) by Matthias Meyer)

My guess is that you would have to be very careful, depending on the author and the subject.